# What is the correct Grails ORM (GORM) implementation to use?

Tags: grails, orm, model, associations, grails-orm

As a result of a change request I need to implement the correct ORM for my Grails application.

I currently have the following simple models and associations:

- Agent

  ```
  static hasMany = [fees:Fee]
  ```
- Fee

  ```
  static belongsTo = [agent:Agent]
  ```

However, now I need to implement the ability for a single Fee to be split amongst Agents. I ended up with the following:

Potential new models associations

- Fee

  ```
  static hasMany = [agentfees:AgentFee]
  ```
- Agent

  ```
  no associations ??
  ```
- AgentFee

  ```
  static belongsTo = [fee:Fee]
  ```

In my mind an AgentFee would contain:

- a reference to a Fee
- a reference to an Agent
- the Agent's % split of the fee (e.g. 80%)

So my question is. Should I also have an association between Agents and AgentFees i.e. something like:

- Fee

  ```
  static hasMany = [agentfees:AgentFee]
  ```
- Agent

  ```
  static hasMany = [agentfees:AgentFee]
  ```
- AgentFee

  ```
  static belongsTo = [fee:Fee]
  static belongsTo = [agent:Agent]
  ```

But this just feels wrong with the multiple belongsTo in AgentFee. What is the best way to implement the notion of "Fee Splits" using GORM?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: have you tried `static belongsTo = [fee:Fee, agent:Agent]` ?

Comment: Thank you for that. I haven't tried that but my question is more - is the way I'm modelling this correct to begin with? Is my approach to "Fee Splits" correct?

Comment: looks fine for me, however, from my experience - if you don't use scaffolded controllers (most of the time you don't) nor you use automatic db schema creation (also, you shouldn't), then using belongsTo and hasMany properties brings more pain than gains - personally, I only put a reference as a regular field in domain class instead of belongsTo, and skip hasMany at all

Comment: @kamil if you don't use hasMany how do you map your one-to-many relationships? Your advice seems unsound.

Comment: I too would be concerned if you do not use hasMany for one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @Michael I put my comment into separate answer below because it was too long, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are changing the relationship to a many-to-many. Here is the documentation for that: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany

A many-to-many relationship needs a joining table at the DB level. However, you most likely don't need a domain for your joining table i.e. you don't need AgentFee. GORM will know to use a joining table.

The only time you need a domain object for your joining table is if the joining table has additional columns beyond the ones needed to facilitate the many-to-many relationship. In this case you would create a domain for the joining table and then create two one-to-many relationships, one in each direction.

Comment: Thanks for this. Re. - not needing a domain for the joining table in a many-to-many except for when the joining table has additional columns beyond the ones needed to facilitate the many-to-many relationship - on this occasion I need to know the % of the Fee the Agent is entitled to. So that would lead me to believe I need your second example which is "a domain for the joining table and then create two one-to-many relationships, one in each direction." i.e. what I have outlined above in my original question looks correct in your opinion?

Comment: @JohnR yes, it looks correct. I looked at some code I have that has a joining table with additional columns for a many-to-many and mine looks just like yours (i.e. two belongsTo in the joining domain)

Comment: Many thanks, it just felt a little "odd" but great to get some clarification

Answer (score 0):

answering questions from comments:

@Michael @John if you look at the underlying database tables then you'll see only a foreign key from one table to another, tables do not cross reference unless it's one-to-one, so simplifying the domain classes like I described earlier changes nothing in physical data and it's easier to maintain in your code (you don't have to use `addTo()` and `removeFrom` methods), you just create a dependent object and set it's reference to current (you always change only one thing)

```
Agent a = new Agent()
Fee fee = new Fee(
```

also, if you want to retrieve all related objects, you can create a property returning list like

```
class Fee {
    Agent agent
}
class Agent {
    List<Fee> getFees() { 
        Fee.findAllByAgent(this) 
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
Agent a = new Agent()
List<Fee> aAgentsFees = a.fees
```

of course it's read only, and if you want to create them:

```
Agent agent1 = new Agent()
Fee feeA = new Fee(agent: agent1)
Fee feeB = new Fee()
feeB.agent = agent1
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage here to using hasMany all I see are disadvantages. First, using hasMany is the standard GORM way of handling many sided relationships so a future maintainer of your code is going to have to figure out how your code is working and why you did it that way. Also, your way doesn't let you take advantage of bulk set operations (removeAll and retainAll) to manage adds/updates/deletes of the many side of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, it is also much appreciated - but just to add, be mindful of this from the documentation: "The default cascading behaviour is to cascade saves and updates, but not deletes unless a belongsTo is also specified"

Comment: @Michael I'm not saying that I am right, and your wrong, I'm just saying what my 4-years of grails experience brought :) earlier around 2.0.0 version there were problems with unit tests involving hasMany relationships, also - together with colleagues - we noticed that if you want to connect two objects, you had to both set the relation on belongsTo side as well as use addTo on the other side, which brings possibility to forget about one of them - after 5 or 6 grails projects I stopped using hasMany/belongsTo and I also treat dynamic finders as if they were private, thats what works better 4 me

Comment: @JohnR - yeah, maybe but if you use db migrations and at least partially manage your database schema yourself, you can then easily set database cascades on delete, and it would work the same